# H.323 to RTSP gateway?

Tags: rtsp, rtp, rtmp, video-conferencing

Is there such a thing as a H.323 to RTSP gateway? Am I searching for the wrong terms? [This site](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/rtsp/faq.html#rtsp_rtp_h323) seems to imply that such a thing should already exists, but I cannot find anything at all. My end goal is to connect a Flash applet (via RTMP) on one end to a video conference (which uses H.323) on the other end. I have a RTMP<-->RTSP/RTP gateway, so a RTSP<-->H.323 gateway would allow this solution to work.

Comment: Well, at least it sounds interesting ;).  I wondering, probably the Codian/Tandberg IPVCR has the potential to do what you want, but I'm not sure it will be in the way you really want it (proprietary and not very flexible usually, plus expensive).